# Formatting of Strings in Latex in whitespace insensitive environment / Z-Notation Schema

Tags: latex, tex, xelatex, z-notation, xetex

I'm using latex to model a few functions using [Z-Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_notation), however, I'm having issues showing a string for output.  In this reduced example code, the text in the quotes has a different formatting from what I would expect.  What can I use to keep the formatting the text inside the quotes to be the same in the code snippet?

Edit: The `overDraftMessage` should be `messageOutput`, missed changing this when creating a reduced example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{oz}   % oz or z-eves or fuzz styles

\begin{document}

\begin{schema}{function}
    messageOutput!: $STRING$ \\
\where
    messageOutput! = ''Output looks strange.'' \\
\end{schema}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution from @lburski works, but tilde is not for this purpose. It should be used to make hard space (non-breaking space). To write space in whitespace insensitive environments, you need to escape it - write backslash before every space: `''Output\ looks\ strange''`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a space between the words on your string `''Output looks strange.''` then try putting a tilde '~' between those words. So you string ends up being `''Output~looks~strange.''`